# How to inspect result of `node --prof` on x64 MacOS X 10.7?

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, profiling

I try to profile my node.js script at CLI.

As written at https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler, or http://blog.arc90.com/2012/03/05/profiling-node-programs-on-mac-os-x/ a do:

```
$ node --prof my_script.js
```

All ok, I get file named `v8.log` with bunch of lines.

But then in inspection tools all go wrong.

```
$ tools/mac-tick-processor v8.log
```

show to me

```
Statistical profiling result from v8.log, (298 ticks, 237 unaccounted, 0 excluded).
```

and empty **JavaScript** section.

```
[JavaScript]:
  ticks  total  nonlib   name
```

Also I try https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler, but get some results too.

How I can work with --prof results?

```
$ node -v
v0.8.18

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.7.4
BuildVersion:   11E53
```

Comment: In case your script is a web app and you want to profile it during load testing or on request you could also try out Nodetime (http://nodetime.com). See this post http://blog.nodetime.com/2012/05/cpu-profiling-with-nodetime.html

Comment: @DmitriMelikyan Actually its CLI-script. In one hand its possible to wrap logic into simple web-app, but in other - I need something for CLI. I love CLI, its fast and easy. But any way, I`l try it

Comment: Just found this node.js module which seems to be doing something similar (and works) - https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by @Dogbert you can use [github.com/sidorares/node-tick](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick)

Feel free to create pull request if you missing any functionality. I haven't updated it for quite a while and it still seems to work

Comment: Oh sir, thank you very much. You just gave a happy ending to a day of the worst kind of programming frustration one can get.

Answer (score 3):

After Node 4.4.0:

`node --prof-process isolate-0xnnnnnnnnnnnn-v8.log > processed.txt`

From: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/